# SSIS ETL Process Design Advice

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssis, etl

I am new to using SSIS and was hoping to get some advice for designing an ETL process.

I have provided a graphic of the overall project. In short, I am taking Excel files from individual Blobs, transforming them to fit a common template format, and then loading them into a SQL Server Database. I am asking for help simply with what the control flow (of the ETL process) should look like. In my past attempt, I had a process in which I would download the files to my local drive, but that's less than ideal.

Ideally, I want to never download the files onto my local drive, rather do the whole process via Azure.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*Project Scope:*

[image: Project Scope Photo]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this will be dependent on interface - what interface are you using to grab these files and process them with SQL server?

This is an important question because if you are using something like a web service or file share across a network to access these items, it might make more sense to grab the files first in SQL server (using a C# CLR for example) and then process/parse/whatever you need to do, then insert them into the appropriate blob field on your SQL destination.  Is this a data interface?  Are both endpoints using Microsoft SQL OLE DB drivers?

To transfer the files you will need a source and destination set up in your SSIS package;  the source and destination will need to be configured for each endpoint, to set these up, simply right click on the Connection Managers pane and add your two data endpoints.

Then you will need to set up a Data Flow Task.  In the flow task you will add a source that references one of the connections you set up in your connection managers.  For each of your vendor blobs you may need to set up a separate data flow task depending on whether or not the data is consistent across the board and also if each vendor uses the same DB connector (in other words, is this the same interface for each vendor or is it not)

Map data from your source to your destination - here I am thinking that you will be drawing a line from your source (which you can make dynamic using variables and by using an OLE DB Custom Query to massage data for example)

You will connect the dots from your source to your destination and keep the items you want.  Note that you will have to follow destination table rules - for example you may need to keep foreign keys or you may not, so you want to make sure the data you move across fits the destination data model.  SSDT is very effective with helping you map things, try the above items and let me know if you have problems!